# How to use death saves

Tags: dnd-5e

I have learnt a lot so far about dungeons and dragons but now I have one more question. what are death saves and how do I use it?

Comment: [Meta of great relevance](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5270/15469).

Comment: What research have you done into answering this question yourself? Have you read section on death saving throws in the PHB or even the basic rules? Was there anything specific you don't understand?... As Miniman has just referred you to, we can't reproduce  entire sections of the rules but we can better help if there's something specific you don't understand. [We also do expect you to have researched and tried to find the answer yourself before asking here.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is no replacement for an actual rule book and the time that goes into reading it.

Comment: I provided you links to [the free basic rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf) at WoTC in my answer to [your question on 0 HPs.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91406/22566).   Please download those rules and read the discussion on death saving throws on page 75 and 76.  Also, what @Nvoigt said.

Answer (score 15):

Death saving throws are detailed on page 197 of the [Player's Handbook](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rpg_playershandbook), page 76 of the [Player's Basic Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf), page 98 of the [System Reference Document](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf), or page 13 of the Starter Set Rulebook found inside the [D&D Starter Set](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rpg_starterset). These resources fully explain what death saving throws are and how to use them.