# Can you die instantly if you take enough damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-death

If you have a max HP of, for example 27, and you have 0 current HP, and then take another 27 dmg, do you die instantly?

Comment: Question isn't an exact [duplicate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/48125/53087), but one of the answers I think also answers this question.

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.